# API request fails in application, but works in browser

Tags: android, api, rest, https, xamarin.android

So I am trying to get some information from an API (that I have no control over) in my android-application using Xamarin.

And it works grate! I get exactly the information I want if I paste the generated links into Chrome, or use the Chrome extension Postman, but it does not work in my application..

The application is in poc state, so everything is inside the main activity which implements the `ILocationListener` and requests gps updates every 3 seconds, but here is the interesting part of the code:

```
public void OnLocationChanged(Location location) {

        var lat = location.Latitude;
        var lon = location.Longitude;

        _lat.Text = "lat: " + lat;
        _lon.Text = "lon: " + lon;

        // get the vegReference (roadReference) based on the lat & lon
        var url = "https://www.vegvesen.no/nvdb/api/vegreferanse/koordinat?lon=" + lon.ToString("") + "&lat=" + lat.ToString("") + "&geometri=WGS84";

        // ex: https://www.vegvesen.no/nvdb/api/vegreferanse/koordinat?lon=10.399547&lat=63.354658&geometri=WGS84

        var json = new JSONObject(Get(url));

        Log.Debug("url", url);
        Log.Debug("json", json.ToString());

        if (json.GetString("kommuneNr") == "0") return; // bug in API?

        var kommuneNr = json.GetString("kommuneNr");

        var vegReferanse = json.GetString("visningsNavn");

        // get the object id 105 (speed limit) on set vegReference
        // API dok: https://www.vegvesen.no/nvdb/apidokumentasjon/#/get/vegobjekter
        var url2 = "https://www.vegvesen.no/nvdb/api/v2/vegobjekter/105?vegreferanse=" + vegReferanse.Replace(" ", "") + "&inkluder=lokasjon&segmentering=false";

        // ex. https://www.vegvesen.no/nvdb/api/v2/vegobjekter/105?vegreferanse=PV3133HP1m73&inkluder=lokasjon&segmentering=false

        // this (url2) is the one that fails

        Log.Debug("url2", url2);

        var json2 = new JSONObject(Get(url2));

        Log.Debug("json2", json2.ToString());

        // get the speed limit with the heighest id (this should be the latest one (FYI: speedlimits have changed over the years, all speed limits are in the database for historical reasons(?)))

        var objs = json2.GetJSONArray("vegObjekter");

        var list = new List<JSONObject>();


        // getting a list of possible objects based on the kommuneNr (because for some f*ced up reason the result returns objects in other kommunes aswell...)
        for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length() - 1; i++)
        {
            if (objs.GetJSONObject(i).GetJSONObject("lokasjon").GetJSONArray("kommuner").GetString(0) == kommuneNr)
                list.Add(objs.GetJSONObject(i));
        }

        if (list.Count == 0) return;

        var url3 = list[list.Count - 1].GetString("href");

        // ex. https://www.vegvesen.no/nvdb/api/v2/vegobjekter/105/276790644

        Log.Debug("url3", url3);

        var json3 = new JSONObject(Get(url3));

        Log.Debug("json3", json3.ToString());

        // set the speed-limit to the textview.

        var res = json3.GetJSONArray("egenskaper").GetJSONObject(0).GetString("verdi");
        _tvSl.Text = res + " km/t";

    }
```

And the `Get`-method beeing called inside the `OnLocationChanged`, which basically just gets the response as a string:

```
private string Get(string url)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(url);

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                sb.Append(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

The response from the url2-request is this:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

My question is this; why does the link (ref url2) work in a browser, and not in the application.

Any help or pointers on this matter will be appreciated!
Also: link to the project on GitHub: https://github.com/Nemeas/alfaOmega

Comment: Hey! One of the API authors here. I'd also like to get to the bottom of this case. I'm unable to run your Xamarin code at this moment but I'd like to direct you to a programming reference. We've published an open source client for the Java platform. The source code may give you som tips https://github.com/nvdb-vegdata/nvdb-api-client

Comment: @matsa So I actually (finally) got the thing to work by adding the `Accept: application/json` on the request. I did however have to use `HttpWebRequest ` in the `Get` method because the `request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json")` did not work (it kept saying I had to provide a valid property value, or something like that. Also tried using the string value "accept" instead of the Enum/Const(?) HttpRequestHeader.Accept), but the `HttpWebRequest` exposes the `accept` as a property like so: `request.Accept = "application/json"`. This was not needed in the first url to apiv1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a ton of trial and errors I figured out that the problem was that there was a missing header; `accept: application/json` (it seems like this is only a case for the v2 of this api(?)). I tried to add the header using the `WebRequest`, but I kept getting an error whenever I reached the line where the header would be added. However there is this other `WebRequest` called `HttpWebRequest` where the `accept` is exposed as a property instead of through a list, and this works. So the only change I had to make was on the `Get` method, that ended up like this:

```
public static string Get(string url)
    {
        // casting request to HttpWebRequest to expose Accept as a property
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
        request.Accept = "application/json";

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        // getting the response
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            sb.Append(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }

        var res = sb.ToString();

        // returning the response as a string
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: It seems you are right that a _missing_ Accept header is indeed interpreted as an invalid Accept value instead of defaulting to */*. Thanks for uncovering this bug.

Answer (score 0):

This may depends on the `user-agent` value in header. If you provide the user-agent value similar to the browser, it may works.